# Show Woocommerce Payment Methods (Stripe) on custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I am trying to display the Woocommerce payment methods, specifically Stripe, on a custom page (not the checkout page).
I am building a page where a user can buy a subscription so I need to show the users' saved payment methods and the form to fill his card details if he/she wishes to add a new one. So basically the exact same thing that happens on the checkout page using Stripe but on a custom page.

Is there a way to do that and does Stripe for Woocommerce have the selected functions in order to process the payment afterwards and/or save a new payment method if the user has entered a new one?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to do this that's built in to the WooCommerce Stripe plugin, but you could do it by writing custom code that [retrieves a Customer's Payment Methods](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list) (and/or their [`sources`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-sources) if you're using those) from the Stripe API and displaying the information how you wish.

Comment: I found out that there is a way to use the Woocommerce Stripe plugin to process the payment methods but it requires to invoke all the functions that the plugin requires in the specified page. So at the end your answer is way easier to implement and ended up using that.
The only thing that still eludes me is how to save a new payment method in Woocommerce. I present the customer with the required fields to add a new card which is then saved in Stripe but I cannot find a way to also save it in Woocommerce.